# Dashes (any kind) not showing up in table

Tags: tables, punctuation

I'm making a table that contains bond lengths and angles, and I can't get any dashes to show up to indicate a bond.

I have typed (ETA entire table code):

```
\begin{table}[hbp]
\caption[Selected bond lengths and angles of \ce{(Ph4P)2[Mn(Cl4Cat)3]}]{Selected bond lengths and angles of \ce{(Ph4P)2[Mn(Cl4Cat)3]}~\cite{Ruiz200076}. symmetry code: I = $x, y, -z+1/2$}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\hline \hline
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\emph{Bond Lengths (\AA)}} && \multicolumn{2}{c}{\emph{Bond Angles (deg)}} \\
\hline
Mn(1)––O(11) & 1.892(6) && O(11) –– Mn(1) –– O(12) & 85.6(2) \\
Mn(1) –– O(12) & 1.885(5) && O(11) –– Mn(1) –– O(21) & 90.8(2) \\
Mn(1) –– O(21) & 1.877(6) && O(11) –– Mn(1) –– O(11\textsuperscript{I}) & 92.9(4) \\
 &  && O(11) –– Mn(1) –– O(12\textsuperscript{I}) & 90.8(2) \\
 &  && O(11) –– Mn(1) –– O(21\textsuperscript{I}) & 175.1(3) \\
 &  && O(12) –– Mn(1) –– O(21) & 92.7(2) \\
 &  && O(12) –– Mn(1) –– O(12\textsuperscript{I}) & 174.8(3) \\
 &  && O(12) –– Mn(1) –– O(21\textsuperscript{I}) & 91.2(2) \\
 &  && O(21) –– Mn(1) –– O(21\textsuperscript{I}) & 85.7(3) \\
\hline

\end{tabular}
\label{tbl:x-raybondsMn}
\end{table}
```

And what I get is:
[image]

Why are the dashes gone?  Using - or --- also doesn't show up.  Taking the spaces out from between results in no space at all showing up (i.e. Mn(1)--O(11) comes out as Mn(1)O(11) )

This is super annoying since I literally copy/pasted the table formatting from another table where dashes ARE showing up, replaced it with the manganese info, and poof all dashes are gone.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. I can't reproduce the problem with the code you have posted. Please edit your question so that it includes a complete example that reproduces the problem. Without this, it may be difficult for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 9):

TeX usually converts two hyphens `--` to an en dash. However, the code snippet is using an Unicode en dash (`–` U+2013) instead of the hyphen (`-` U+002D).

After a rewrite with the hyphen character the dash should be visible.

Comment: Explain?  Typing "-" or "--" or "---" all results in the same thing, which is no type of dash or hyphen whatsoever. Is there some code to make a dash show up?

Comment: @hmc73: You are using the wrong input character. You need the ASCII hyphen, not the Unicode en dash. Try a different editor.

Comment: Aha!  Using TeXShop instead of TeXworks was successful.  Thank you!